# Is it possible to determine the location device of mobile networks - Nativescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, location, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to determine the location of the device in a way other than gps in Nativescript ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do some research before asking. It is absolutely trivial to find https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/location

Comment: I'm interested in this option - to explore the location without GPS, you need to turn it off on the device.

Comment: isnt this question just `How can i get the device's gps location without the use of gps`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the **nativescript-geolocation** plugin requests for high accuracy which uses mostly Network / Wifi to determine location.

Comment: If the GPS is turned off, then he will still determine the location in a different way?

Comment: @VolodyaKurpita no because the app needs the device's permission to be able to get the gps data

Comment: You can't turn off GPS and expect it to work. If you go to GPS settings, you will have 3 different options ranging from High (uses the best option out of Network / Wifi / GPS), Battery Saving (Wifi / Cellular Network), and Device Only (GPS). The plugin by default requests for high accuracy if a different accuracy is selected or if itself is turned off.

Comment: The documentation states that it "Defaults to `Accuracy.any`" and not to the high accuracy.

Comment: @str That is when it makes a location request. But still the plugin asks for high accuracy when it attempts to check location settings. I'm not sure it's a bug or something they made it for reason. But I'm sure that's how it works.